# Pre-flight request is authenticated even if CorsFilter is enabled in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cors, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring Security for OAuth authentication and I have configured the Cors. However, my all preflight request fails dues to authentication since the preflight request does not have a token(That is how it should be). I have the following configuration class;

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity security) throws Exception {

        security.cors()
                .and()
                .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/health")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();

        // Custom filter to validate if user is authorized and active to access the system
        security.addFilterAfter(new AuthorizationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","HEAD","POST","PUT"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

**WebMvcConfiguration .java**

```
@Configuration
public; class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("GET","HEAD","POST","PUT");
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Why preflight request goes to authentication even if I have CorsFilter enable?
2. How can I exclude preflight request to be authenticated ?

**UPDATE:**

I enabled log for debugging the issue using `logging.level.org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy: DEBUG` in application.yml file.

I fetched the list of filter registered in filter chain and list is as follow :

```
class org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
class org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
class org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter
class org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter
class org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter
class org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter
class org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
class org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
class org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter
class org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter
class org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor
class org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter
```

Notice that corsFilter is registered. However, when I get request only following filters are running and not CorsFilter;

```
'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
'HeaderWriterFilter'
'LogoutFilter'
'BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter'
'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
'SessionManagementFilter'
'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
```

**UPDATE 2:**

While testing, I noticed for '/actuator/health', CorsFilter is being called. But I am not sure what does that mean?

Comment: You're not allowing the `OPTION` method

Comment: Do I have to explicitly add `OPTIONS` method? is not that automatically added?

Comment: @DarrenForsythe Even for other request(GET, POST, PUT) it is not calling cors filter.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to your configuration `security.cors()` should have enabled the CORS filter which should enable the pre-flight request to work without an authorization token.But it seems you have configured your requests machers incorrectly, please use correct url mappings so that the security configuration will apply to all endpoints.

Also,Try setting your allowed origins as well to cover all origins:

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","HEAD","POST","PUT"));
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

Guide : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-entry-points

Comment: I have added `security.cors()` already and made the changes in origins. Still, CorsFilter is not getting called for the request other than `"/actuator/health"`

Comment: Can you remove the requestMatchers() entry so that the springboot default works. Now you have configured only the endpoint /actuator/health for this to work.

Comment: If I remove requestMatchers() then authentication is not triggered.

Comment: The current configuration that you are using only matches to the endpoint /actuator/endpoint. Please go through the documentation to understand what each method represents and reconfigure it.

Comment: Use just http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**") for matching all requests.

Comment: Use just http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**") for matching all requests.